# Split value in single row to multiple rows with Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

With Postgresql I have the query:

```
select '1' , '2', '3';
```

with result

[image]

I would like to have next result:

```
column
1
2
3
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an array and then use UNNEST():

```
SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `Unpivot`, then you can try to use  `UNION ALL`

```
select '1' column
UNION ALL
SELECT '2'
UNION ALL
SELECT '3'
```

or you can try to use [JOIN LATERAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-table-expressions.html)

```
SELECT s.*
FROM test t
JOIN LATERAL (VALUES(t.a),(t.b),(t.c)) s(column) ON TRUE
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=78a686ece3bf87bc7035081b219b51c2)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use a table function for that:

```
SELECT CAST(i AS text) FROM generate_series(1, 3) AS i;
```

Comment: It doesn't work with: SELECT i FROM ('1','2') AS i;

Comment: Oh, you want strings. Fixed.

Comment: SELECT CAST(i AS text) FROM ('1', '2') AS i; RESULT -> ERROR: syntax error at or near "1"

Comment: @DavidLeon: please read the answer: it uses `from generate_series(...)` not `from ('1', '2')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the question is with String

Comment: @DavidLeon: it's not about numbers vs strings. You used `from (...)` whereas this answer uses `from generate_series(...)`

Comment: I thought that the objective was to generate a table with three rows, which are the strings `'1'`, `'2'` and `3'`. If I misunderstood, perhaps it was because the question didn't explain the real goal so that I could understand it.